# Excel 2010 : Help in Change font in multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA script for changing fonts in multiple workbooks kept in one folder. However, it is not working. Please take a look at the code

```
    Sub changefont()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, fpath As String, fname As String
fpath = "D:\reports"
If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
fname = Dir(fpath & ".xls")
Do
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fname)
Set sh = wb.Sheets("REPORT")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not sh Is Nothing Then
With sh.Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(90, 11))
.Font.Size = "18"
.Font = "Arial"
End With
End If
wb.Close True
fname = Dir
Loop While fname <> ""
End Sub
```

NB : my Sheet1 is named as REPORT in all the workbooks

Comment: please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**Untested**). I have added the comments at the relevant section. Do let me know if you get an error or if you have any questions.

```
Sub changefont()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Dim fpath As String, fname As String

    fpath = "D:\reports"

    If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"

    fname = Dir(fpath & ".xls")

    Do While fname <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fname)

        '~~> This is important
        Set sh = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = wb.Sheets("REPORT")
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not sh Is Nothing Then
            '~~> You need to fully qualify the cells object
            With sh.Range(sh.Cells(10, 1), sh.Cells(90, 11))
                '~> Font Size is not a string
                .Font.Size = 18
                '~~> Add .Name
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
            End With

            wb.Close True
            DoEvents
        Else
            wb.Close False
        End If

        fname = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, @siddharth-rout Thanks for the help, but it is not working.